# Use separate file to extend documentation

Tags: c#, doxygen

I am using Doxygen to document some huge projects written in C#. The existing documentation in these projects should not be changed.

Is there any way to extend the existing documentation and provide some doxygen commands for certain classes or methods in a separate file?

For example, lets say there is the class ViewModel.cs, which is documented like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines a ViewModel that can be bound to a TreeList control.
/// </summary>
public abstract class ViewModel : IViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the root elements to be displayed in the TreeList.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<ITreeNode> Elements { get; protected set; }
}
```

Is there a way to create a separate file (.dox) that will be linked to that class and extends the existing documentation? E.g. to group the class into a specific module with the \ingroup command.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, no such tool exists. C# uses assemblies and namespaces for conceptual grouping of APIs. Defining a manual grouping separately would only serve to confuse users who are familiar with the language.

For the best results, you should use C# documentation comments along with the latest release of [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) or [my fork of the project](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/SHFB) (which uses a slightly different presentation style). These tools are more cleanly integrated into Visual Studio, and work continues on features like IntelliSense extensions and code completion within documentation comments (Roslyn+SHFB is quite good but I still want to see it further improved). The following page shows a fairly recent documentation build using the latter:

http://openstacknetsdk.org/docs-master/